# 'Undefined Reference' when trying to access class in another file

Tags: c++

So basically I am making this simple program that adds numbers but keep getting the error 'undefined reference to tent::boom'.  I  have been tinkering with the code for hours and looked at many different solutions but none of them seem to work for what ever reason so I am sorry if  a  similar version of this question has been asked before.

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "tent.h"


using namespace std;


int main()
{
    tent bo;
    bo.boom();

    return 0;
}

//tent.h
#include <iostream>

class tent
{
public:
    tent();
    int boom();

protected:
private:
};

//tent.cpp
#include "tent.h"
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int boom()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c = a + b;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cout << c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What I did was changed boom in tent.cpp to tent::boom